# Counting while compressing in LZW?

Tags: python, string, algorithm, text, lzw

**Note: This is not the right use for LZW compression. I am just playing around with it.**

### Question

In a single pass, is it possible to also update the frequency counts of the elements inside the dictionary?

### My implementation

```
import sys
from collections import defaultdict
import re

# The silliest string!
inputString = "this is the first sentence in this book the first sentence is really the most interesting the first sentence is always first"
inputString = inputString.lower().split()

StringTable = defaultdict(int)
FreqTable = defaultdict(int)

def DoPass():
    global inputString
    global StringTable
    global FreqTable

    print ""
    print "INPUT STRING:"
    print inputString

    CODE = 256

    STRING = inputString[0]

    output = []

    StringTable[STRING] = CODE
    CODE += 1

    total = len(inputString)

    for i in range(1, total):
        WORD = inputString[i]

        if STRING + " " + WORD in StringTable:
            STRING += " " + WORD
        else:
            if STRING in StringTable:
                output.append(str(StringTable[STRING]))
            else:
                output.append(STRING)
            StringTable[STRING + " " + WORD] = CODE
            CODE += 1
            STRING = WORD

    StringTable[STRING] = CODE
    CODE += 1
    output.append(str(StringTable[STRING]))

    print ""
    print "OUTPUT STRING:"
    print output

    print ""
    print "Dictionary Built..."
    for i in sorted(StringTable.keys(), key=lambda x: len(x)):
        print i, StringTable[i]

    print ""
    print "Frequencies:"
    for i in sorted(FreqTable.keys(), key=lambda x: len(x)):
        print i, FreqTable[i]

def main():
    DoPass()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### Output

```
INPUT STRING:
['this', 'is', 'the', 'first', 'sentence', 'in', 'this', 'book', 'the', 'first', 'sentence', 'is', 'really', 'the', 'most', 'interesting', 'the', 'first', 'sent
ence', 'is', 'always', 'first']

OUTPUT STRING:
['256', 'is', 'the', 'first', 'sentence', 'in', '256', 'book', '259', 'sentence', 'is', 'really', 'the', 'most', 'interesting', '265', 'is', 'always', '275']

Dictionary Built...
this 256
first 275
is the 258
in this 262
this is 257
book the 264
the most 269
this book 263
is always 273
is really 267
the first 259
really the 268
sentence in 261
sentence is 266
always first 274
first sentence 260
interesting the 271
most interesting 270
the first sentence 265
the first sentence is 272

Frequencies:
#### I am trying to fill this
```

I want to fill the `FreqTable` with the frequency counts of whatever patterns it is finding. I did not put my method here for obvious reasons - it does not work and it gives me wrong counts. Any suggestions on whether this is possible would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand your question.
If you just need the Frequency Table, then this should be straightforward : each time you find a pattern, you just add +1 to its frequency count.
So the real problem should be to find the pattern.

If you want to keep the patterns in sorted order, this should be pretty easy too, since you keep the table sorted all the time, it ends up being an insert-sort operation, which is extremely quick.

Now, finding the right pattern is another story.
You need a tree, or a hash table followed by trees, or by lists, or whatever, to find your best matching sequence. This is what makes such algorithm more complex to execute.

Obviously, for very small data set, a "naive" search (testing all entries one by one) could give some results. But with expanding data set, the search cost will become prohibitive.